# How is this NOT injective and IS surjective?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider
$$ p : \mathcal P(\{1,2,\ldots, n\}) \to \{0,1,2,\ldots, n\}, \quad p(S) := |S|. $$

I know injective means 1-1 and surjective means onto. When I read this, I read the power set of S is equal to the cardinality of S. I must be reading this wrong. Could someone point me in the right direction. 
Thank you.

Comment: How is this confusing?  It's clear it is not injective, right?  To prove it is surjective you  just need to find a subset with each of the possible orders.

Comment: $p$ is a function that sends some element $S$ of $P({1, 2, ..., n})$ to $|S|$. Note the difference between small $p$ and capital $P$.

Comment: Not all p-s are the same p.

Comment: For the empty set, $n=0$, its a bijection.

Comment: $p$ is a function, for a  set $S$, you define $p(S)=|S|$. Don't get confused $p$ and $P$ are different things.

Comment: @Wuestenfux.  And for $n=1$ so $\mathscr P(\{1\}) = \{\emptyset, \{1\}\}\leftrightarrow \{0,1\}$ .  ANd $p(\emptyset) =0$ and $p(\{1\})=1$ is a bijection.  But for $n > 1$ it clearly is not.  (Or as "clearly" as understanding what this notation and symbol means; that can be obscure and abstract to the inexperienced.)

Comment: "How is this confusing? It's clear it is not injective, right?"  Well, if you don't realize that $p$ and $\mathscr P$ are different symbols and you don't get that the $:$ and $\to$ indicate function notation and you don't know what the set $S$ is and you think it is somehow telling you $\mathscr P(S) = |S|$ and you know that $|\mathscr P(S)| = 2^{|S|} \ne |S|$ then.... well, then it can be confusing because you have no idea what it *is* saying and the only sense you make out of it is gibberish and you know enough to know it *is* gibberish and not enough to know what it *IS* actually saying...

Comment: For $n=0$ you get $P(\emptyset)$ since you start with 1.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Right.  If $n=0$ and $n=1$ you get bijections.  And for $n > 1$ you don't.  $\{\emptyset\}=\mathscr P(\{\})\leftrightarrow \{0\}$ and $\{\emptyset,\{1\}\} =\mathscr P(\{1\})\leftrightarrow \{0,1\}$.  But $\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\} =\mathscr P(\{1,2\})\not \leftrightarrow \{0,1,2\}$.  (And, of course, $2^0 =0+1$ and $2^1 = 1+1$ but if $n > 1$ then $2^n \ne n+1$.)

Answer (score 1):

Small $p$ is a function.  Big $\mathscr P$ is the power set symbol.  Different things.

The domain of the function is $\mathscr P(\{1,2,....n\})$.  The codomain of the function is the set of  integers from $0$ to $n$. In other words:

$$p:\mathscr P(\{1,2,....n\})\to \{0,1,...,n\}$$

The function is simply that $p(X) = $ the number of element in $X$.  In other words:

If $S\subseteq \{1,2,3.....n\}$ the $$p:S \mapsto |S|$$ or in other words

$$p(S) = |S|$$

SO for example $p(\emptyset) = 0$.

And $p(\{1,2,3,....., n\}) =n$.

And $p(\{2,3,7\}) = 3$ and so on.

If $n> 1$ then $p$ is obviously not injective as if $|X| = |Y|$ but $X\ne Y$ then $f(X) = |X| = |Y| = f(Y)$.  (Example:  If $n\ge 7$ then $p(\{1,2,3\}) = p(\{2,3,7\}) = 3$.

[Also:  $|\mathscr P(\{1,2,3,....n\}| = 2^n$ and $|\{0,1,2,3,....,n\}| = n+1$.  If $n> 1$ then $2^n > n+1$ and you can't have an injection for a set of higher cardinality to one of a lower cardinality.]

[On the other hand if $n=1$ then $\mathscr P(\{1\}) = \{\emptyset, \{1\}$ and $p(\emptyset) =0$ and $p(\{1\}) = 1$ and $p$ *is* a bijection $\{\emptyset,\{1\}\} \leftrightarrow \{0,1\}$]

[Oh, and as  Wuestenfux points out in the comments:  If $n=0$ then $\{\} =\emptyset$ and $\mathscr P(\emptyset)= \{\emptyset\}$ and $p: \{\emptyset\}\to \{0\}$ via $p(\emptyset) = |\emptyset| = 0$.  That is also a bijection.  ]

[Worth noting (maybe) That $|\mathscr P(\{\})| = 2^0$ and $|\{0\}| = 0+1$ and $2^0 = 0+1$.  And $|\mathscr P(\{1\}| = 2^1$ and $|\{0,1\}| = 1+1$ and $2^2 = 1+ 1$.  But for $n>1$ then $|\mathscr P(\{1,...,n\}) = 2^n$ and $|\{0,1,...n\}| = n+1$ and $2^n > n+1$.]

[Or maybe that *wasn't* worth noting...]

And $p$ is clearly surjective as $p(\emptyset)=0$ and for any $k; 0< k\le n$ then $p(\{1,2,.....k\}) = k$.

That's all the statement is saying..

Comment: This makes sense then. I thought since p is a function and we feed it n, then that n is put into Big P which finds the power set of n and the cardinality of Big P is always 2^(# of elements in the set). Might be thinking too much on it, thanks to all for commenting.

Comment: Notation can be confusing when you haven't seen it enough times.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $n\geq 2$, then
$$p(\{1\}) = p(\{2\}) = 1, $$
but $\{1\} \neq \{2\}$, therefore $p$ is not injective. For surjectivity, take $0\leq k\leq n$, then any subset $S$ with $k$ elements in it satisfies
$$p(S) = k. $$
In case of $k=0$, it holds that $p(\emptyset) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

It is *not* injective since the domain contains more elements than the codomain (a meagre $n$ compared to the $2^n$ in the domain).

It is surjective because each of the integers from $0$ to $n$ gets assigned to some subset of $\{1,2,3,\dots\}.$ This follows since the list of subsets of a finite set can always be made to proceed from the empty set, to a singleton, to a pair of objects, etc., each time adding just one element, until the available objects are exhausted.